# Cloning existing python project anyjson setup command error

Tags: python, django

I have this project shared to me via github, after I clone and run this steps:

```
python -m venv ./venv
venv\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in pip install -r:

It gives me this errors:

```
 error in anyjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anyjson==0.3.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for anyjson==0.3.3
```

Here is what inside the requirements.txt

```
  amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.25
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.13
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-axes==1.7.0
django-celery==3.2.2
django-compressor==2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-dynamic-formsets==0.0.8
django-polymorphic==2.1.2
django-reversion==3.0.1
djangorestframework==3.7.4
ffs==0.0.8.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.7
Jinja2==2.10
kombu==3.0.37
letter==0.5
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
opal==0.14.2
Pillow==8.1.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2019.1
rcssmin==1.0.6
requests==2.20.1
rjsmin==1.0.12
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.3
whitenoise==4.1.4
mysqlclient==2.0.3
cryptography==3.4.1
```

Already tried removing `anyjson` from requirements.txt but still gives me error. What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

There was a breaking change in the setuptools package that's causing this error. This will require a config change on our side, downgrading setuptools to a version prior 58 like:

```
pip install "setuptools<58"
```